# Escaping to another country while I-130 is in progress

Tags: visa, immigration

I have a question for those who have some knowledge of immigration procedures.

I live in Venezuela with my wife (American-born citizen) and our daughter. We filled an I-130 on June last year, the USCIS case track hasn't updated and it still says the case has been received. A few months ago I followed some suggestions from other forum members to call USCIS and place and inquiry for expedited processing in view of our situation here in Venezuela (lack of food, medicine, no personal security, losing my job, etc). The USCIS answered the inquiry and they denied the request for expedited processing, arguing that we didn't provide enough evidence (they never asked about it neither we received information on how to send it).

Anyway, we feel that we need to escape from Venezuela, frankly, the conditions here are unbearable, the currency has lost all its value, food is extremely scarce. We are considering escaping to Argentina, although it will diminish considerably our funds for an eventual move to the US.

I have 2 questions regarding this. If we move to Argentina and our I-130 is approved, can we continue there the immigration process or would we have to travel back to Venezuela to continue the process?

Comment: Will you be staying legally in Argentina?

Comment: The Venezuelan passport is valid to enter Argentina, we`ll try to get a work permit in order to not diminish our funds to finally move to the US.

Comment: Just because the passport is 'valid to enter Argentina' doesn't mean that you will legally be able to *reside* in Argentina. Does Argentina immigration law allow for entry and subsequent residency? Do you qualify for such? Argentina is certainly a lot more stable, but it isn't exactly a rich country, and your plan sounds an awful lot like an economic refugee plan.

Comment: You are right, we would be travelling to Argentina only to escape the situation here in Venezuela and wait for the USCIS approval, but our plans will never be to reside there permanently, our fixed north is USA. My question is about the possibility to continue our USCIS case in Argentina. We have all our papers ready to move even work in Argentina while we wait, currently is not difficult to stay legally there.

Comment: @COPITO - This strikes me as a sensible plan, if you think that Argentina would give you some relief.  Also, I suggest you try again with a request for expediting, since now you know that more documentation is required.

Comment: Thank you @aparente001. Do you think each time we request for expediting our chances of it getting reviewed sooner diminish?

Comment: @COPITO - I have no idea.  But if your first request was rejected for insufficient documentation, I wonder what you have to lose in resubmitting with the documentation that you now know is required?